# Adding Web API to MVC 5 project (API takes over)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've gone over all stack over flow QAs and online tutorials, to add a Web API to my current MVC project.

The Web API works, the MVC works only if I put the routing path into the url.

I want the MVC routing to come up as default, but for some reason it always tries to do the API logic.

I'm hoping its something simple I've missed

What I have done so far.

**Web API Config class**

*Default, not really changed anything*

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {// Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**MVC config class**

*Default, not really changed anything*

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



    }
}
```

**Global Config class**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);





    }
```

**API Controller class**

*Default, not really changed anything*

```
public class RegistrationController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Registration
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Registration/5

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

**MVC home Controller class**

*Default, not really changed anything*

```
namespace MVCPortal.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }        
}}
```

This is the error I'm getting
[image]

Comment: I can't seem to set a default routing or start with MVC etc...

Comment: Check Properties -> launchSettings.json file. Should be able to configure startup url there. By asp.net 5 you mean .net core right?

Comment: @ChrisCooper show home controller?

Comment: You need to set your startup project to multiple. Right click your solution > Properties > Common Properties > Startup Project select Multiple and set the Action to Start for your MVC and API projects.

Comment: Hi Max its Core, I don't seem to have a launchSettings.json file.  
Nkosi.  I'll edit the question and add the home controller.
jomsk13.  I can't run multiple project as the API and the MVC are within one project, but thankt